# A table for a poem?

Tags: html

Right, you shouldn't use tables for your layout, I got that.

But my poem has many lines and needs some line-counting, e.g. every fifth line will be numbered.

My idea: A table!

The left column for the poem, the right one for the lines.

Just to check with the profis: Is that all right? I can't think of anything easier than that... Thx!

Comment: Nope, still not acceptable. If you want to number the lines, you can use CSS counters, but you'd have to mark up your poem a little differently from just simple <br> for line breaks - or you could use JavaScript. But a table is still a no-no.

Comment: Tables are for tabular data.

Comment: You could use CSS to create a table-like layout, without actually using a `<table>` tag. As @BoltClock suggests, you can also use pseudo-elements (like `:before`) to add line numbering with CSS only. Though I think CSS numbering would hinder usability for screen readers and search engines who will not have the numbering available in the actual markup.

Comment: Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the CSS nth-child pseudo class? You can use `<p>` paragraph tag for each line then apply the following CSS

```
.poem p:nth-child(5n+5) {  
  whatever;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a solution. The numbers of the lines would not build a straight vertical line this way...